# Grading/feedback on school assignments

Tags: discussion, feedback

I'm not that new to Stack Exchange, but I wanted to ask a question about something that I'm not sure is acceptable on the platform.

I am currently studying for a degree in Finance and Accounting, so I often use various parts of SE for help in my studies.

The structure of my studies requires several ***ungraded*** practice questions to be answered. Do you think it would be acceptable to get a general opinion on my answers using SE? Ie, posting the question followed by my answer, then asking the community's opinion on how I went about answering it?

Comment: As soon as you venture into "asking the community's opinion" territory, you're generally getting outside of the scope of the network. Do you have a specific example of such a question?

Comment: No particular example, but suppose we're doing something like algebra. I have an practice activity that I've got the correct answer for, but want to see if my working is optimal or could be improved. Could I show my working and ask for opinions on how to improve or optilise it?

Comment: you probably should ask on the Meta specific to the site your question would be posted at. So, if you are thinking about an algebra problem, maybe try asking on Mathematics meta if they are fine "reviewing" your work for mayor problems.

Comment: I wonder if you could ask "is there a better/more direct/faster/simpler way to solve this using [method]?" That's not asking for an opinion on your solution, merely asking whether there are other ways to get to the answer? But I'm guessing that each site will need to weigh in on that.

Comment: That specific example (could I make these algebraic workings more efficient?) would probably be at home on Mathematics SE (I think I've seen similar questions), but as Catija says, you should probably ask on their Meta first. @Catija, I think you have the beginnings of an answer there. Want to write it up as one?

Answer (score 5):

We generally don't welcome overly subjective content and asking for the community's opinion on your solution would probably get closed as "primarily opinion based".

However, I think you can rephrase your question in a way that will be welcome.

For example, with your algebra question, you could rephrase it as:

> This is the solution I got for an algebra problem I'm working out. I am trying to find out if there's a more efficient/direct/simple way to solve the problem than how I've gone about it. [include problem & solution]. This problem needs to be solved using [method].

This way, you're not asking people to "grade" your solution, you're asking if there are alternate ways to get to the solution. You might also consider explaining why you think there may be a "better" solution to your question - for example, "My solution is correct but it seemed like a convoluted method to get there.

If your answer is the best solution, that may be the response you get.

That said, this is one of those things that's probably going to depend on the site, so you should consider asking on the child meta for the site you're using whether this type of question would be acceptable. If you use chat, you might also ask there, but having a meta question to point at when you ask the question and get pushback is better.

If they tell you that the question is off topic or too subjective for the site, it may be welcome in chat, so consider going there.